# Failed to build ndicapi

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pip, scikits

I am trying to install this python library from [SciKit-Surgery](https://github.com/SciKit-Surgery/scikit-surgerynditracker) on a windows machine, but no matter what I try I get the following error.

> error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for ndicapi
>
> Running setup.py clean for ndicapi
>
> Failed to build ndicapi
>
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for ndicapi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have edited my PATH variables to include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx64\x64" and that didn't help.

I also loaded up Visual Studio and used the built in terminal to run "pip install scikit-surgerynditracker" but I get the same error.

I made sure to have every checkbox marked for "C++ Desktop Development" when installing Visual Studio / Visual Studio Build Tools.

What am I  missing to install this library? From what I understand there's something going on with CMake but I have no experience with CMake.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by using [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win) and using python 3.9.13. Seems that there are some issue with python 3.10+ on Windows with this specific library. Not sure exactly what they are, but this solved the issue for me.